# access to boost:shared_ptr outside main scope crashes with Assertion failed: px != 0. What is the correct use of a pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library

Access to cloud that is of type boost:shared_ptr crashes with a Assertion failed: px != 0 error outside main, but inside main it is OK.

I am going to use PCL in a Qt program where I need to have access to a pointer to cloud outside the scope where this pointer is declared f.ex in MainWindow::classxyz() so I wrote this test program to illustrate my problem (see below)

How can I use a pointer correctly to be able to access the cloud pointer also outside the scope of main? (and Qt, outside the scope of MainWindow:MainWindow() as I will initialize the pointer in the constructor)

pcd_read.h:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;
void outside();
```

pcd_read.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include "pcd_read.h"

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("C:/Users/user2/Documents/qt_test_kode_div/pcd_file_scope_test/build/Debug/test_pcd.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }
  std::cout << "Loaded "
            << cloud->width * cloud->height
            << " data points from test_pcd.pcd with the following fields: "
            << std::endl;

            std::cout << cloud->size();     //This works

  outside();                                //When I call outside() the code crashes inside outside()

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i)
    std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].y
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;


  return (0);
}

void outside()
{
    std::cout << cloud->size();         // This crashes. Why does accessing cloud cause a crash related to Boost? Assertion failed: px != 0
                                        // The pointer seems to not be initialized. 
                                        // I want the pointer to be accessible also in outside without passing as a parameter. How can I achieve that?
}
```

Comment: `cloud` used by `outside` is not the same variable as `cloud` that `main` sets. One is a global variable, the other is a local variable within `main`.

Comment: I get the same problem if I declare it as a private in a class. I can access it OK in the Constructor where it is initialized. However in another method of the same class, I get a crash. So there is something more to it than just wrong scope. Because then the compiler should complain I would expect?

Comment: So you have a similar or different problem when you do that. Sadly, I'm unable to assist with code that I cannot see.

Comment: The same thing happens so lets focus on the above example. How can I avoid a crash in outside() when accessing a method in the object pointed to by the cloud pointer?

Comment: Don't declare a local variable named `cloud` in `main`. Have `main` assign to the global variable instead. As written, the global variable `cloud` is null - it doesn't point to any object; that is why you see a crash in `outside`

Comment: "Because then the compiler should complain I would expect" - I'd call that a rather flawed expectation. Shadowing variables is perfectly legal (even though error prone).

Comment: Yes you are probably right Jesper. I am new to shared pointers. Can someone explain why this crashes and how to fix it pls.

Comment: It crashes because the variable is null. It's null because you never assign to it. Instead, you assign to a different variable, that just happens to have the same name. This is not in any way specific to shared pointers; the fact that you use `shared_ptr` is an irrelevant red herring. I don't know how to explain it any clearer.

Comment: "Can someone explain why this crashes" - @Igor already did. Just because you name two things the same that does not make them the same thing. You have two *different* `cloud`s.

Comment: @Igor already explained. Change `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);` to `cloud = new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>();`

Comment: @ChrisD can you explain the difference? In your example cloud is a "normal pointer", not a shared pointer? 

My code is taken from som PCL example code. So why do they use a shared pointer in the first place? I see from most examples that they tend to use shared pointers. 

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php

Comment: My syntax is likely incorrect, it should probably be 

```cloud = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);```

But the main point (no pun intended) is that you were _declaring_ a new, locally scoped variable called `cloud` inside main. You should be _assigning_ to the global variable called `cloud`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared another variable with the same name `cloud` inside `main`.

Therefore, the global one isn't visible inside `main`, and left unused, UNTIL you call `outside`, which then still refers to the unused global.

Answer (score 0):

As @chrisD mentioned, changing the pointer initialization to a regular pointer solved it.

.h:

```
//pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;    // original -- CRASHES OUTSIDE SCOPE - smartpointer ... 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> *cloud;          // changed to normal pointer -- now no crash ... since it is inside scope
void outside();
```

.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include "pcd_read.h"

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);        // Causes a crash when cloud is outside of scope
    cloud = new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>();    //Initializes pointer the std. way instead

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("C:/Users/user2/Documents/qt_test_kode_div/pcd_file_scope_test/build/Debug/test_pcd.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }
  std::cout << "Loaded "
            << cloud->width * cloud->height
            << " data points from test_pcd.pcd with the following fields: "
            << std::endl;

            std::cout << cloud->size();     //This works

  outside();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i)
    std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].y
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;


  return (0);
}

void outside()
{
    std::cout << cloud->size();         // Now OK
```